# Why doesn't my Access query work in my program?

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, oledb

I have a method that is supposed to enter the name of a file into a microsoft access database.
I receive a syntax error in my `INSERT INTO` statement at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`. See code below:

```
 public static void LoadToDB(string path){

        int lastindx = path.LastIndexOf('\\');
        string pc = path.Substring(lastindx+1);
        string cmdStr = "INSERT INTO image (file_name) VALUES ('"+pc+"');";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdStr, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
        Console.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText);
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
```

When I debug and check the value of the command string when the syntax error occurs it is

`"INSERT INTO image (file_name) VALUES ('DCM1004');"`

This command executes fine when I copy and paste it directly into Access but not when my program tries to execute it. I've seen a few questions similar to this and most of the answers suggest that the poster is using a reserved word and needs to wrap the column name in square brackets (`[file_name]`). I've tried this and had no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you just tried brackets around [file_name]? What about [image]?

Comment: Does it work if your file name is `DCM'1004`?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, 'image' needed square brackets too. New query command text looks like:

"`INSERT INTO [image] (file_name) VALUES ('DCM1004');`"